# Printing Eye Coordinates through OpenCV tracking

Tags: c, opencv, coordinates, eye-tracking

I have managed to perform some simple face and eye detection/tracking. It's not too accurate but it works. I was wondering if there was some way in the OpenCV library where I could extract the coordinates of the eyes and face as it moves and print it out in the console in real time. Or maybe even save these coordinates in an output file.

UPDATE (Code for face and eye detection):

`int detect( IplImage* img, const char* cascade_name )
{`

```
static CvMemStorage* storage = 0;

static CvHaarClassifierCascade* cascade = 0;

int scale = 1;
int i;
IplImage* temp = cvCreateImage( cvSize(img->width/scale,img->height/scale), 8, 3 );
```

//Load Cascade

```
cascade = (CvHaarClassifierCascade*)cvLoad( cascade_name, 0, 0, 0 );

if( !cascade )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "ERROR: Could not load classifier cascade!\n" );
    return 0;
}


storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
cvClearMemStorage( storage );
int faceDetected = 0;
if( cascade )
{
    //In case there is more than one face
    CvSeq* faces = cvHaarDetectObjects( img, cascade, storage,
                                       1.1, 2, CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING,
                                       cvSize(40, 40) );

    faceDetected = (faces ? faces->total : 0);

    for( i = 0; i < (faces ? faces->total : 0); i++ )
    {

        CvRect* r = (CvRect*)cvGetSeqElem( faces, i );
```

//Maybe this is where I get the coordinates?

```
        pt1.x = r->x*scale;
        pt2.x = (r->x+r->width)*scale;
        pt1.y = r->y*scale;
        pt2.y = (r->y+r->height)*scale;
```

//Draw rectangle over face

```
        cvRectangle( img, pt1, pt2, CV_RGB(255,0,0), 3, 8, 0 );

    }
}
cvReleaseImage( &temp );   
return faceDetected;
```

}

Comment: yes you can. no need to wonder.

Comment: I should have been more direct. My question is how? What methods would I call to do this. I tried looking on the OpenCV docs and couldn't find anything that was straightforward for me. I'm new to computer vision FYI.

Comment: show me the function in your code that detects eye or face

Comment: Just edited my original post.

Comment: you have yourself marked the portion where you are getting the co- ordinates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly this is what you want :

```
for( i=0 ; i< faces->total; i++ )
{
 CvRect* r = (CvRect*)cvGetSeqElem( faces, i );
 printf("( %d %d ) , ( %d %d) ", r->x, r->y, r->x + r->width, r->y + r->height ); 
}
```

Comment: Awesome. This will surely help. I have another question regarding OpenCV. I've been able to do everything real time. But sometimes it gets really slow, my computer is not that powerful when it comes to handling high resolution video displayed on screen real time. Is there a way I can perform the tracking on an input video, can someone guide me through the documentation on how to do it? Is it as efficient? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html#cascade-classifier) is a simple face detection built in opencv. They detect eyes within the faces with another `CascadeClassifier`. You can download list of existing `CascadeClassifiers` from [opencv repository](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository/revisions/master/show/data) and use them for your needs. If neither of them satisfy your requirements, you can always train your own classifier, follow [this tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html), for example.